# PHP (int) for variables in MySQL query. Secure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am using following method for MySQL queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `myTableId`=" . (int)$myId;
```

Is this a completely safe method or is there a way to inject some sql into the database with this method?
Any better alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can lead to unintended consequences, e.g.

```
$myId = 'blahblahblah';
```

would result in

```
... WHERE myTableId=0
```

maybe not such a big deal in this case, but if (say) you're doing a permissions systme and "super-duper-ultra-high-level-user-with-more-power-than-god" has permission level 0, then it's a nice way to bypass security.

Comment: I don't like the example. what prevents the user from entering literal 0?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Nothing – and in case of MySQL the first auto-increment value of a column is always 1 (one) to prevent such mistakes…

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want to avoid SQL injection, your best bet is to use PDO and prepared statements. check out http://www.php.net/pdo and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Sure, but do you really need a prepared statement in every case? `$database->exec('DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ' . (int)$uid . ';');`

Comment: @feeela so to say - yes. The whole point of prepared statements is make the developer not to thing of the matter yet be safe. And it can be acheived only if used with no exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Thís should be perfectly save, without any drawbacks, as long as the input can be casted to int.

Answer (score 0):

make it like this

```
$sql="select `username` from `users` where id='$newid';";
mysql_query($sql);
```

here $newid is the int value.
The symbol used before and after username, to get this you have to press the key just below esc .

Comment: If you see a question where you can post the exact same answer, the correct thing to do is vote or flag the newer question as a duplicate of the older one. It's rare that the same answer is correct for two completely different questions.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably use sprintf instead - but I dont see that it is much different from what you are doing. Placing the integer in quotes may also help.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `myTableId`='%d'", $myId);
```

Should probably add that you may want to deal with the case when conversion to integer fails. So dont have a table zero.

Comment: what does it mean - "Placing the integer in quotes may also help"? How it can help alone?

Comment: Because then it gets passed as a string to mysql rather than an integer or possible a special character that could be used for injection

Comment: Did I say that just adding quotes magically protects you from all sql injection? No I dont think I did!

Comment: I think you did. As you didn't say anything else.

Answer (score -2):

No need for the Int if you are just worrying about the mysql injection.
To prevent mysql injection you can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

What you have right now will block all mysql injection if your mysql condition is only for int but if the situation is like this:

```
$username = $_GET["username"];
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$username'
```

if the $username value is **\' OR 1** your in trouble or i should say your dead

if the $username value is **\'; DELETE FROM customers WHERE 1 or username = ** your very dead + doomed

To prevent this from happening use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]);
```

Comment: oh. that grave delusion again. mysql_real_escape_string is not for preventing injections. and your answer WILL lead to injection.

Comment: Plese read this first before you say some accusations http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Or at least google or research first? Or you could explain me why mysql_real_escape_string will not block injection. Then I will accept that I am wrong.

Comment: if the OP will do what you say, `$myId = mysql_real_escape_string($myId)`; he'd got the query vulnerable to sql injection. So, in your place I wouldn't say that `"No need for the Int if you are just worrying about the mysql injection. To prevent mysql injection you can use mysql_real_escape_string."`. For the explanation you can refer to the links you posted.

Comment: yeah thats why I says 'What you have right now will block all mysql injection if your mysql condition is only for int but if the situation is like this'.

Comment: And also $myId = mysql_real_escape_string($myId) will also block sql injection.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a proper answer.

Comment: well, you have just to phrase it different. If I were you, I'd phrase it as "you can always treat numbers the same way as strings, **enclosing them in quotes** and escaping using  mysql_real_escape_string()". That's the point: both these actions are useless alone. Both works only together. See, mysql_real_escape_string is not something that makes your data magically "safe". roughly speaking it's just escaping quotes you are using as a string delimiters, that's all. So, outside of quotes it's just useless. you can escape `$myId='1;drop table users;'` a zillion times but injection remains there.

Comment: ok. it seems you just don't understand how it works. I am giving up.

Comment: :D sorry. I think I need to study this stuff I forgot that you are a master hehe. Sorry I will just study this thing maybe when I have time.

Comment: @Leysam If you don't wrap your value into quotes, mysql_real_escape_string() will not prevent a SQL injection. You need to test whether it's an int

Comment: I see. Thank you guys. I learn a lot here :D
Im just 17 anyway there is more for me to learn.