# using a php variable in the WHERE clause of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm running a very simple query that I think should work. The only thing that I haven't done before is put a php variable in the WHERE clause of the query.  The variable $X is a numerical value, say 100.  When I run this query, I just get a value of 0 returned.  Am I doing something obviously stupid?

```
SELECT generator_64k.n
FROM generator_64k
WHERE generator_64k.n<= '$X'
```

I've looked around the web and also tried this:

```
SELECT generator_64k.n
FROM generator_64k
WHERE generator_64k.n<= '" . $X . "'
```

But this also just returns 0.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the PHP code around? In PHP MySQL queries are just strings that get send to MySQL via sockets. Without the PHP code that constructs the string (your query) we cannot help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP (int) for variables in MySQL query. Secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068234/php-int-for-variables-in-mysql-query-secure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, or post your PHP code.

```
<?php
$X = 100;
$query = "SELECT n FROM generator_64k WHERE n <= $X";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
   echo ('Query error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT generator_64k.n FROM generator_64k WHERE generator_64k.n<= {$X};";
```

Comment: Sadly this returns an error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @user1262890 edited the post. I missed a semi-colon in SQL syntax too. Changed from `{$X}";` to `{$X};";`

Answer (score 0):

E.g of php and using variables
$query = "select * from table1 where col1 <=" .$myVariable;

$result= mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function returns false on error (false == 0), otherwise, it returns a resource. mysql_query does not return the value from the result set. You must use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or something similar to fetch the rows from the result set.

Also, ensure that you wrap the query in double quotes so PHP can expand the variable `$X`.

Use [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to fetch the error from the last call to mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

make it like this

```
$sql="select `username` from `users` where id='$newid';";
mysql_query($sql);
```

here $newid is the int value.
The symbol used before and after username, to get this you have to press the key just below esc .

Answer (score -2):

You can't have `'` around your numeric value. MySQL will treat it as string.

You should do this instead

```
" WHERE number <= " . (int)$val . " .. "

// or (but not recommended due to security problem)
" WHERE number <= $val "
```

Comment: No, MySQL does not care if you pass integers as `'5'`. It will simply be converted before usage. Do your research!

Comment: php does not need casting variables

Comment: the cast `(int)$val` is pointless as your `integer` `$val` gets immediately cast back to `string` due to the `string` concatenation. MySQL won't know what type a PHP variable had. You just pass queries as strings to mysql.

Comment: I can't believe there's people that still don't know the risk of sqli njection.

Comment: Man why don't you just accept some good criticism and learn from them? Of course I know about SQL injection. It makes me really sad, that your nonsense claim about `'` around numeric values is still up.